# Connection Strings in App.config

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

Seems like I ran into a similar problem as [tlitterio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1816309/tlitterio) in his [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333273/is-there-a-bug-with-the-new-entity-framework-5-in-an-mvc4-project-with-a-data-ac).

I am using [Daniels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/261653/daniel) first mentioned approach [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14277960/2766251), my ViewModel has a parameter-less constructor and the ConnectionString is in all Projects of the Solution in App.config like this:

```
  [...]
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="DataBaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLTEST;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\DataBase.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  [...]
```

With this [post](http://schaedlerdaniel.wordpress.com/2011/07/) [german, at the bottom] i guess, it is the DataAccessLayer, that is called in the parameter-less constructor, causing the trouble.

I am kindly asking, if someone could briefly explain, what is happening on startup exactly in that regard, or why this (see below) exception in DesignTime is thrown.
Or, what is to be made sure, before instantiating my viewmodel in xaml?
(I just found this [here](http://chanmingman.wordpress.com/2013/11/21/no-connection-string-named-anyentities-could-be-found-in-the-application-config-file/) is pointed out, that it need to be in the startup-project.)

```
"InvalidOperationException" wurde in "MainWindwoViewModel" ausgelöst: Eine Instanz von "MainWindoeViewModel" kann nicht erstellt werden. Klicken Sie hier, um Details anzuzeigen.

No connection string named 'DataBaseEntities' could be found in the application         config    file.
 bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ConnectionHasModel()
 bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
 bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
 bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
 bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
 bei System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
 bei System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
 bei System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
 bei WpfApplication1.DataAccessLayer.GetAllCustomers() in C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\test\WpfApplication1\DataAccessLayer.cs:Zeile 107.
 bei WpfApplication1.ViewModel.MainWindowViewModel..ctor() in C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\test\WpfApplication1\ViewModel\MainWindowViewModel.cs:Zeile 299.
```